# SQL Query - Subquery returns more than one row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Table:

```
laterecords
-----------
studentid - varchar
latetime - datetime
reason - varchar
```

My Query:

```
SELECT laterecords.studentid,
laterecords.latetime,
laterecords.reason,
( SELECT Count(laterecords.studentid) FROM laterecords 
      GROUP BY laterecords.studentid ) AS late_count 
FROM laterecords
```

I'm getting " MySQL Subquery Returns more than one row" error.

I know a workaround for this query to use the following query:

```
SELECT laterecords.studentid,
laterecords.latetime,
laterecords.reason 
FROM laterecords
```

Then using php loop to though the results and do below query to get the `late_count` and echo it out:

```
SELECT Count(laterecords.studentid) AS late_count FROM laterecords
```

But i think there might be a better solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple fix is to add a `WHERE` clause in your subquery:

```
SELECT
    studentid,
    latetime,
    reason,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM laterecords AS B
     WHERE A.studentid = B.student.id) AS late_count 
FROM laterecords AS A
```

A better option (in terms of performance) is to use a join:

```
SELECT
    A.studentid,
    A.latetime,
    A.reason,
    B.total
FROM laterecords AS A
JOIN 
(
    SELECT studentid, COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM laterecords 
    GROUP BY studentid
) AS B
ON A.studentid = B.studentid
```