# Sql query returns "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT *, (SELECT fsi.active
           FROM filters_sorts  AS fsi
           WHERE fs.`active`= '1' AND fs.`parent` !='0')
FROM filters_sorts  AS fs
WHERE fs.`active`= '1' AND fs.`parent` ='0';
```

[table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dm4rL.png)

Comment: [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to improve your question

Comment: actually i need more rows from inner query also from same table.

Comment: You query has no sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: If subquery is used in SELECT statement then the result it returns must contain only one row. Yours (`SELECT fsi.active FROM filters_sorts AS fsi WHERE fs.active= '1' AND fs.parent ='0'`) returns more than 1.

Comment: @NikNik  I need data from same table as inner data because outer query based on parent = 0 returns parent menu and inner query returns sub menu based on  parentn !=0

Comment: @Spectarion  I need data from same table as inner data because outer query based on parent = 0 returns parent menu and inner query returns sub menu based on parentn !=0

Comment: Show as your table structure. Take a screenshot or something.

Comment: @Spectarion Image added Please Check

Comment: Update your question and use proper formatting. Then clarify what you want to achieve (in your question).

Comment: Maybe this would help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445179/sql-query-subquery-returns-more-than-one-row?rq=1

Comment: Do a join instead. Or have a correlated sub-query.

Comment: @jarlh send me small example

Comment: @jarlh check this SELECT *
FROM filters_sorts AS fs
 INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM filters_sorts  AS fsi WHERE fsi.`active`='1' AND fsi.`parent`=fs.`id`
)  AS innner 
WHERE  fs.`parent`= '0' AND fs.`active`='1' returns "Unknown column 'fs.id' in 'where clause'"

Comment: check this SELECT *
FROM filters_sorts AS fs
 INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM filters_sorts  AS fsi WHERE fsi.`active`='1' AND fsi.`parent`=fs.`id`
)  AS innner 
WHERE  fs.`parent`= '0' AND fs.`active`='1' returns "Unknown column 'fs.id' in 'where clause'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below query instead:

```
SELECT fs1.name menuName, fs1.id menuId, fs2.id subMenuId, fs2.name subMenuName
FROM filters_sorts fs1
LEFT JOIN filters_sorts fs2 ON fs1.id = fs2.parent
WHERE fs1.parent=0
```

You can add desired fields in `SELECT`

if you want a single row for one main category you can do it as:

```
SELECT fs1.name menuName, fs1.id menuId, GROUP_CONCAT(fs2.name) subMenuName
FROM filters_sorts fs1
LEFT JOIN filters_sorts fs2 ON fs1.id = fs2.parent
WHERE fs1.parent=0
GROUP BY fs1.id
```

Comment: menuName           menuId  subMenuId  subMenuName         
-----------------  ------  ---------  --------------------
Price                   8          9  Less Than ₹ 500   
Price                   8         10  ₹ 500 To ₹1000  
Popularity              1     (NULL)  (NULL)                                                                     if possible i need like this "Price     8     Less than 500,₹500 To ₹1000" for each price and based on parent id make comma separated in subMenuName     !!!! Thanks  @Anshuman Jaiswal

Comment: yes, it will you have to do some manipulations at client side where you are going to use this result. From SQL you won't be able to find `tree` structure

Comment: updated answer may be you need this, here all submenu will be comma separated

Comment: thanks . . for example i need all join data of "Price submenu" as alias for that Price. .

Comment: hope it helps you, if so don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: Finally Done Thanks A lot ....  SELECT fs1.name menuName, fs1.id menuId, GROUP_CONCAT(fs2.name) subMenuName
FROM filters_sorts fs1
LEFT JOIN filters_sorts fs2 ON fs1.id = fs2.parent
WHERE fs1.parent=0
GROUP BY fs1.id

Comment: Small Doubt actually i have sorting column ..I need to sort for both  join query as well as for main query .................Im trying this  SELECT fs1.*, GROUP_CONCAT(fs2.name)  AS subMenuName
FROM filters_sorts fs1
LEFT JOIN filters_sorts fs2 ON fs1.id = fs2.parent ORDER BY fs2.`sorting`
WHERE fs1.parent=0 ORDER BY fs1.`sorting`
GROUP BY fs1.id  which is not working

Comment: `ORDER BY` should be after `GROUP BY`